# Running/Execute a Query on StackExchange Database

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Often i have seen some user (*with 10-15k+ Rep*) mentioning some details related to them.

One such example can be seen on [user BoltClock description area](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/27163/top-users-singapore).

What i want to know is, how a user can have access SO DB for such queries (*with schema*)....does it comes with some minimum reputation barrier or limited to moderators only?

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) is open to all. You have even linked to it directly in your question.

You don't even have to register with the site to write your queries.

Comment: i thought users can make their own custom queries in it!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor - yes. That's what the big "compose query" button on the right is all about.